# Minimization problem of the Fiedler vector

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am currently stuyding spectral graph theory and in my slides I stumbled on the following solution to obtain the Fiedler vector:
\begin{align}
  \min_x x^T L_G x \\
\text{s.t. } x^T x = 1 \\
x^T \vec{1} = 0
\end{align}
$L_G$ is the graph Laplacian of an undirected graph and the Fiedler vector is the eigenvector corresponding to the second smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_2 $.
This is obviosly related to the Rayleigh-Ritz Theorem that states that we can compute the second smallest eigenvalue as:
\begin{align}
  \lambda_2=\min_{x\perp {v_1}}\frac{x^TL_Gx}{x^Tx}
\end{align}
I have the following questions:

1. Why do we use $x^Tx=1$ as a constraint and how is it connected to the Rayleigh-Ritz Theorem ?
2. Do we use $x^T \vec{1}=0$ as a constraint to guarantee that we are minimizing over the vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue ? ($\vec{1}$ is in the graph Laplacian always an eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue)

Comment: 1. we use $x^Tx=\|x\|^2 = 1$ to get rid of the denominator of the RR theorem

Comment: As Exodd notes the condition $x^T x = 1$ is just a convenient normalization (a scaled eigenvector is an eigenvector for the same value, so there's nothing lost in looking for one of norm $1$). Condition (2) guarantees that $x$ is orthogonal to the space spanned by the vector $1$, which from what you've said is at least *part* of the eigenspace for the smallest eigenvalue. Implicitly, some theory about "graph Laplacians" (or hypothesis on the graph?) guarantees that this eigenspace is *spanned* by $1$, i.e. that the smallest eigenvalue is "simple." A full answer would cite/provide this theory.